# Как сказать "young blood" по-русски?

Tags: одним-словом

There is a slang English phrase "young blood" which can be used in place of "you".  When a person speaks to someone who is significantly younger, and wants to indicate that something this younger person did or is in the act of doing is immature and nonsensical, they can address the younger person as "young blood".  Typically this phrase implies that the two people don't know each other intimately, like a parent and their child.  Watch up to 3:06 of "Uncle Drew: Part 1" on youtube for example use cases of "young blood".  How would you say "young blood" in Russian?

Answer (score 12):

It depends on the level of how harsh ones want to sound. If the intention is just to indicate that somebody is too young and incompetent but by no means to offend, then `молодо-зелено` will be the best choice, like in:

> Эх, молодо-зелено, ты бы научился сначала токарным станком пользоваться, а потом уж лез.

If speaker doesn't care too much about being offensive, `щенок` (pl. щенки; literally, a puppy), [`молокосос`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81) (pl. молокососы, literally; a milk-sucker) or [`сопляк`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BA) can be used.

Also, there's (quite rude) [phrase](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE) `молоко на губах не обсохло`.

But in you case I'd rather go with `молодёжь`, like in

> Эх, молодёжь, ну что, сразимся?

This is used exactly when you are slightly ironical but actually friendly.
Also, sometimes it's stressed differently - `мóлодежь` just to sound bit more ironical.

One thing for sure - you should never ever try to translated it literally, since "молодая кровь" (or "свежая кровь") in Russian means something almost exactly different. It's about some fresh power, some younger and healthier forces that community needs to continue to evolve.

Comment: КМК "Эх, молодёжь" особенно в ироничном смысле отсылает к мультфильмам о муравье-торопыжке. "Солнце скроется муравеёник закроется". Если найти ссылку на ю-тюб можно вставить наверное

Comment: Some people say "молодняк" or "мо'лодежь и под'ростки" with the first syllable stressed.

Comment: There's also "молодой человек" which can also be used ironically e.g when a 70-years-old addresses a 40-years-old.

Answer (score 3):

`сынок` - is very close, especially, when there is no family ties at all. But it is a little bit *offensive*.
Example: `учись, сынок, папа покажет` ≈ `look, young blood, daddy show you how to do it`

Comment: Guess that has direct equivalent in English - "sonny" - though I (maybe wrong) associate it with wannabe mafia speak

Answer (score 3):

I guess, the most neutral word is the adjective `зелёный` (green). I would use it.

`Он совсем ещё зелёный!` - Mean, he doesn't have enough experience!

You can say even it to a person you don't know well:
`Какой же вы/ты ещё зелёный!` Or `Вы /ты ещё совсем зелёный.`

It doesn't sound offensive or so.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth noting that in Russian there is literally an idiom of "молодая кровь"  (or  "свежая кровь"), but its meaning is completely different even almost the opposite, positive, as we see. Meaning in the young strength and energy of someone, or the "reinforcements" of/for something ("влить молодую кровь")

Comment: with only this information this is more of a comment since it does not answer the question.

Comment: but this information is useful and related this

Comment: It does but so does relevant comments - answer by definition is an attempt to provide an answer or add valuable additional information to the answer provided. Since there's no firm line between a valuable additional information and just comment - sometimes I feel that I'm no in my right to convert to a comment as a mod. But as a regular user I can just down-vote and explain why I actually did it.

Comment: "Young blood" and "fresh blood" - the difference is significant within this question context. What you are talking about is mostly "fresh blood". Good point otherwise.

Comment: DK, https://spark.ru/user/103327/blog/47176/kak-najti-svezhie-idei-i-vlit-moloduyu-krov-v-svoj-biznes        https://sakhalinmedia.ru/news/787936/     https://clck.ru/MLkXH    et cetera; it depend on context.